# httphandler cannot find axd of Highcharts

Tags: asp.net, highcharts, iis-7, axd

I am working on project that use Highcharts library for charts, I have added export module for exporting to (pdf,png,..) and it's work fine on development environment but when I deployed the project to IIS 7
I get the following error when I exprot any chart to any extention:

> HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
>
> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

```
Requested URL: http://localhost/HighchartsExport.axd
```

Note:

the following HttpHandler added to web.config:

```
<add verb="POST" path="HighchartsExport.axd" type="Tek4.Highcharts.Exporting.HttpHandler, Tek4.Highcharts.Exporting" validate="false" />
```

so, What's the problem? and how I can fix it?

Comment: Maybe any port is blocked?

Comment: I don't think that, because website work on the same port

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HighchartsExport.axd httpHandler is added to System.Web section of the Web.Config file. In IIS7, it should be added under System.Webserver section as following

```
<add name="HighchartsExport" path="HighchartsExport.axd" type="Tek4.Highcharts.Exporting.HttpHandler, Tek4.Highcharts.Exporting" verb="POST"  />
```